# how to solve SLIR image does not exist issue?

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

I am using slir to resize my images, I installed it on my cpanel as recommended in the slir github instructions, but I got an error that the image does not exist, here is the image link:

```
$src = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/slir/?w=144&h=81&c=1000:564&i=".Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/images/articles/$a->image";
```

any details needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to change some variables values in slir configuration file, try to assign the dir of slir by yourself, and also assign the abse dir by yourself, as follow:

```
public static $documentRoot = 'your root dir here'; // for example: '/home/username/public_html';
```